# Sublime text 3, в устройстве нет диска

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Когда ввожу в js слэш в кавычках, возникает такого рода ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что за бред и как исправить?

Comment: VostokSisters, смотрите, Byulent не пользовался Sublime Text, но нагуглил ответ, который Вам помог. В будущем переводите текст ошибок (ибо на английском почти всегда находится больше информации) и вводите в поисковик запросы вида `Sublime $Ваше сообщение об ошибке$`. А лучше сразу пользоваться англоязычной ОС. Текст из окон в Windows, например, можно извлечь при помощи [**SysExporter**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/sysexp). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я вообще вводил "plugin host exe"

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я вводил подобное сообщение об ошибке на английском, это слишком очевидно. Но не нашел ответа. А товарищ Byulent нашел. Такое бывает.  А что, засорил форум несколькими килобайтами, да?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/auto-complete-causing-a-plugin-host-exe-no-disk-message/15763

Судя по всему, это связано с работой одного из плагинов автодополнения. Плагин пытается автоматически определить путь до файла и начинает искать его на всех дисках системы. Но реализовано это так, что опрашиваются все доступные дисковые *приводы*, а не имеющиеся в них *диски*.

Грешить этим могут следующие плагины:

- FuzzyFilePath
- File System Autocompletion
- AutoFileName

Попробуйте отключить какой-либо из этих плагинов и посмотрите на работу.

Comment: Спасибо, решение безотказное, конечно :D Это был третий плагин. Посоветуйте какой-нибудь аналог, который не глючит? Заменить-то чем-то надо...

Comment: @VostokSisters, не могу точно знать, с Sublime не работал.

Comment: @VostokSisters, [**SideBarEnhancements**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements). Добавляет в command palette [**множество аналогичных команд**](https://github.com/SideBarEnhancements-org/SideBarEnhancements/blob/st3/Commands.sublime-commands). Спасибо.